# How does one find out if a product is consumable or not?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

In my code I do not wish to save any products in NSUserDefaults that are consumable after a purchase call back. I tried SkProduct class to see if it gave that information but it does not. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

In the [SKProduct](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html) object, you can set `productIdentifier` to anything you want.

For example:

- Consumable Items product id could start with GGG-XXXXXXX
- Non-Consumable Items product id could start with KEEP-XXXXXX

Then in your application just check the prefix of the productIdentifier.